# How to modify a stored procedure using SQLCMD for MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlcmd

Suppose a stored procedure as follows have been created using the Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

```
use testbase
go
create procedure testtable_pricesmaller
    @pricelimit money
as
select * from testtable where price = @pricelimit;
go
```

Is it possible to modify a stored procedure using `SQLCMD` for MS SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have the permission to do so then there should be no reason why you could not. The following example assumes that you are using Windows Authentication:

```
sqlcmd -E -S computer\instance -d database

alter procedure testtable_pricesmaller 
@pricelimit money
as
select * from testtable where price = @pricelimit;
go
```

Alternatively if you have an existing script file that has the command you want to run you could use the `-i` option to run that file:

```
sqlcmd -E -S computer\instance -d database -i file.sql
```

Here is some more information on the sqlcmd utility that you should find helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

I hope this helps you.